# Seeking a deeper understanding of the global keyword inside of functions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

First post on Overstack.

I'm new to Python and coding in general. I'm now learning about functions and presently looking at some examples that describe global variables on [Python-Course.eu](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php):

```py
def f():
    global s
    print(s)
    s = "Only in spring, but London is great as well!"
    print(s)
s = "I am looking for a course in Paris!" 
f()
print(s)
```

Which yields the output:

```
I am looking for a course in Paris!
Only in spring, but London is great as well!
Only in spring, but London is great as well!
```

So my understanding is that the **global** keyword changes the value of the global **s** variable to "Only in the spring, but London is great as well!"? Is that accurate?

If that is the case, if I assign **global** to a variable inside a function and don't assign a value to **s** outside the function, I get an error? Does this mean that the **global** keyword can only modify an already-assigned global variable?

For example, why can't I do this:

```py
def f():
  global s
  s = "Only in spring, but London is great as well!"
  print(s)
print(s)
f()
```

I've noticed that if I run the function first, it works. So does that mean that I have to run the function in order to assign the global variable?

This question isn't so much about trying to get a piece of code to work, but more of trying to understand how Python works and why. Thanks and I apologize if this question has been answered already. I just have not been able to find an answer. Thank you so very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reasonably straightforward, as per the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) (with my emphasis):

> In Python, variables that are only *referenced* inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is *assigned* a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

So, if you assign to a variable *anywhere* within a function, that variables is considered local *everywhere* in the function, leading to issues such as:

```
def fn():
    print(s)    # Use before assignment, despite one s being
    global s    #   set before calling.
    s = 42

s = 7
fn()
```

That means, if you want to *change* a global, you need to *mark* it as global within the function.

If the only thing you're doing is *using* the global, that's not needed, but I tend to mark it anyway, just in case I later want to change it, and for clarity of intent (I use globals infrequently enough that this almost never comes up).

The reason your code sample doesn't work:

```
def f():
    global s
    s = "Only in spring, but London is great as well!"
    print(s)

print(s)
f()
```

is because `s` does not exists at the point where you first print it (before the function call). Even if `global` *did* create the variable, that wouldn't have happened until the function was called, after that first `print`.

In any case, `global` does *not* create the variable, it merely indicates to the function to use the global when assigning. That's evident from the following code:

```
def f():
    global s
    print(s)

f()
```

which also complains about the non-existence of `s`.

---

In terms of *creating* globals, they come into existence when you assign to them. You can assign to them *outside* the function:

```
def fn():
    print(s) # global because function doesn't assign to it.

# Unassigned here
s = 42
# Assigned here
fn()
```

or you can assign to them *inside* a function *if* they're marked global.

```
def fn():
    global s
    # Unassigned here
    s = 42
    # Assigned here
    print(s) # global because you said so.

# Unassigned here
fn()
# Assigned here
```

In the absence of those cases, there is *only* a local:

```
def fn():
    # Global unassigned here ...
    s = 42
    # ... and here
    print(s) # local.

# Global unassigned here
fn()
# ... and here.
```

Comment: So the global variable inside the function effectively does not exist until the function is called. Is that accurate? Is the global variable effectively created once the function is called? I appreciate the insight and the dictionary references.

Comment: @ThreeDogs: A global comes into existence when you assign to it outside of the function or when you assign to it inside the function and it's been marked global. If, inside the function, it's not marked global and you assign to it, it's a local. I'll add an addendum to explain this ...

Answer (score 0):

The first example you need to the look at the sequence of your code. Essentially the code will be in this order based on your sequence.

```
s = "I am looking for a course in Paris!" 
print(s)
s = "Only in spring, but London is great as well!"
print(s)
print(s)
```

The second example why it failed as you haven't declared a variable s. global is just declaring scope of the variable s but you have to define it.

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is the order of statement execution here. As you noted, if you run the function first, it works:

```
# 1 definition of function f - don't parse or run the code inside here, just know it exists.
def f():
  # 4 ... global statement
  global s
  # 5 assign a value to `s` (the global)
  s = "Only in spring, but London is great as well!"
  # 6 run print function with parameter `s`
  print(s)
# 2 run print function with variable `s` as input. `s` doesn't exist. error.
print(s)
# if we pretend we skip the print
# 3 run the function `f`
f()
# After running `f()` `s` is now defined in the global scope
```

What you might find useful to examine this is checking out the contents of `locals()` and `globals()` those are builtin functions that return a dictionary of everything in the scope, so you can see how it changes based on assignments and function definitions.